# Reordering array objects via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been doing some sorting and still dont get it why the result is []. could you guys help me out what im missing?

I have my raw array object:

```
var data = [
 {message:'hello', username:'user1'},
 {message:'data', username:'user1'},
 {message:'sample', username:'user2'},
 {message:'here', username:'user2'},
];
```

my function is:

```
var chat = [];
function reorder(obj) {
    obj.forEach( function(val, i) {
        if(typeof chat[val.username] === 'undefined') {
            chat[val.username] = [];
            chat[val.username].push(val);   
        }
        else 
            chat[val.username].push(val);
    });
    return chat;
}
```

and on my console:

```
reorder(data);
```

I am expecting to have:

```
var data2 = [
  'user1': [{message:'hello', username:'user1'}, {message:'data', username:'user1'} ],
  'user2': [{message:'sample', username:'user2'}, {message:'here', username:'user2'} ],
];
```

Comment: `chat.[val.username]` is not valid syntax, aren't you getting a syntax error for that? Is it actually `chat[val.username]`?

Comment: Where do you assign the result to `data2`?

Comment: Why don't you put the init of 'chat' as first thing into the reorder function?

Comment: @Barmar yes sorry, I edited my post. assuming you have declared var data2 outside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with `reduce`:

```
var data2 = data.reduce(function(acc, x) {
  acc[x.username] = (acc[x.username] || []).concat(x)
  return acc
},{})
/*^
{ user1: 
   [ { message: 'hello', username: 'user1' },
     { message: 'data', username: 'user1' } ],
  user2: 
   [ { message: 'sample', username: 'user2' },
     { message: 'here', username: 'user2' } ] }
*/
```

Comment: COOL! I didn't know there's a function for this!! thanks! man. how did it do that?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you made `chat` an array. When you look at an array in the console, it only displays the numeric indexes, not the named properties; you have to use `console.log(chat)` to see the named properties.

Since you want this to be an object with named properties, you should declare it as an object, not an array:

```
var chat = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Underscore's `_.groupBy`:

```
_.groupBy(data, 'username')
```